# Cast a "-" after a varchar string and then left join another table, sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, casting

I am currently working in SQL Server Visual Management Studio 2012. I have 2 tables. `Table1` has 2 columns; `PartNumber as varchar`, and `dateordered as smalldatetime`. `Table2` has 2 columns, `PartNumber as varchar`, and `time as float`. The part numbers on `table1` are 9 digits long and looks like this `'999999999.'` The `table2` part numbers have an extra `"-"` at the end and will look something like this `'999999999-.'` I need to add the `"-"` to the end of the part number on `table1` and then cross reference that number to table2 and get the time column.

```
SELECT Right('9', cast(varchar, PartNumber)) as PartNumber 
from table1  
  Left Join table2 on table1.partnumber = table2.partnumber 
where DateOrdered BETWEEN ('2015-01-01 00:00:00.000') AND ('2015-05-11 00:00:00.000') 
  AND PartNumber IS NOT NULL
```

-----------------UPDATE
New code-----------

```
select table1.partnumber, table2.time from table1 left join table2 on
table2 + '-' = table1.partnumber
where DateOrdered IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Tip: Always use aliases, e.g. `AND table1.PartNumber is not NULL`, when joining tables. You have an awful lot of `PartNumber` references floating around.

Comment: @HABO yea i see that. I was just trying to get the code running or get the error for that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure about your question, but this is not working?:

```
table1.partnumber + '-' = table2.partnumber
```

(not the most elegant way of doing things)

Comment: are you saying do a basic select statement with a left join and not doing any select right or cast at all?

Comment: As far as I can see you should be able to create a join by just adding the '-' to the partnumber in table1. This does not work very well on very large tables though because string operations take up a decent amount of resources. If both ParNumber columns are of varchar type there is no need to cast them to varchar. If you do need to cast it to varchar you can even do that in the on statement of the join

Comment: I am getting a list of the table1.partnumbers but the time column is all null. I dont think it is picking up the + '-'.

Answer (score 0):

So, your problem is the `table1.partnumber (999999999)` is not like `table2.partnumber (999999999-)` so your `JOIN` clause is not working.
If that's the case, then you can have your `JOIN` like this:

```
Left Join table2 on table2.partnumber LIKE table1.partnumber+'-'
```

Comment: With this my code does run but I am not getting any data returned. let me update my code

Comment: I dont think it is picking up the "-" sign